# Apple não consegue ver meu Ad

Tags: ad, apple

Enviei meu app para revisão, pórem eles dizem que não conseguem localizar meu Ad:

> Your submitted IAP indicate that your app serves advertisements.
>   However, we were unable to locate ads in your app.
>
> Please reply to this message to provide the steps for locating ads in
>   your app. When we hear back from you, we will continue the review.
>
> Since your iTunes Connect Application State is Metadata Rejected, we
>   do NOT require a new binary. To revise the metadata, visit iTunes
>   Connect to select your app and revise the desired metadata values.
>   Once you’ve completed all changes, click the “Submit for Review”
>   button at the top of the App Details page.

Acontece que o Ad esta na primeira pagina, bem localizado e durante os testes nos aparelhos virtuais e no meu iPod eu consigo ver o anuncio, com aqueles defaults da apple. Será que eu esqueci alguma configuração? Alguém tem alguma dica?

Comment: Seu app mostra alguma coisa no lugar do banner caso nenhum ad esteja disponível?

Comment: Ele esconde o ad

Comment: Tentei alerta-los que o aplicativo esconde o app com problema de conexão / servidores, espero que eles o aplicativo passe desta vez.